# Installing Printer

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, printing

I tried installing the Epson printer driver from [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=18787&DSCCHK=cd4ad419e3805cfac26d6492d12e38fc7da11822). It managed to install and when I try to print it goes into the print queue. However when it goes away, the printer does not even print.

This is not the case for the same printer when plugged into a Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, sending the print job means nothing. You can plug your USB cable into a cupcake, and Linux will happily send jobs there. 
What you have to do, is to open this address on your machine:  `http://localhost:631/admin` You will get into web interface of your printing system. There send a test page to print and you will get a real error. My guess it will be "filters" malfunctioning because they lack some libs. Anyway, ask a new question with that data available.

Comment: I did that, L110-Series-14  Test Page  anonymous  1k  Unknown   completed at
Mon 28 Apr 2014 10:27:44 PM PHT